# Adding ACM SSL certificate to Load Balancer not working for EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, https

I have a Bitnami Wordpress EC2 instance. I want to add SSL certificate so that my blog can be accessed with https.

I tried all the steps available in all the tutorials and AWS guide.

Below is the URL of the guide that I followed.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

I add ACM certificate to Load Balancer. When I'm pinging Load Balancer DNS name, it is taking me to non-secured page.

Can anyone help me in that.

Comment: Ping can't take you to a page, it's a very simple "are you there" with a timer. What exactly are you doing? You can use free Let's Encrypt certificates instead of ELB with ACM - I have a [tutorial for Let's Encrypt on Nginx here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-5-free-https-https2-for-wordpress-using-lets-encrypt-aws/).